# Use sqlcmd and setvar dynamically show hide columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sqlcmd

I toggle the display of [PHI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_health_information) when generating data extracts from a vendor's [EHR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_health_record) system.

To date, I've been manually enabling and disabling these fields in my script files:

```
-- PHI enabled
SELECT  MRN
        --,HASHBYTES('SHA2_256',MRN) MRN_HASH
...
GO

-- PHI disabled
SELECT  -- MRN
        ,HASHBYTES('SHA2_256',MRN) MRN_HASH
...
GO
```

Is there a way to do this dynamically?

```
 --
 -- disable this variable when running `SQLCMD` from command line
 -- PS> sqlcmd -E -S server -d database -i .\script.sql -v hide_phi=1
 --
:setvar hide_phi 0

:out c:\users\x\desktop\patients.csv
SELECT
       <if $(hide_phi)=0 then hide MRN>
       <if $(hide_phi)=1 then hide MRN_HASH>
...
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLCMD accepts variables.  You can simply pass in the variable to your .SQL file, and inside your file, do a conditional check on the variable value.  You could use a CASE statement to check value of the variable, and return the appropriate value.

Pseudo sample query:

```
select "MRN" = case 
   when '$(hide_phi)' = '1' then HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', MRN) 
   else MRN
END
...
GO
```

or possibly this:

```
select "MRN" = case '$(hide_phi)'
   when '1' then HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', MRN) 
   else MRN
END
```

More info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714.aspx

Comment: Well...kinda.  I would actually like remove the `MRN` column from the results altogether, rather than just changing its content.

Comment: adjust the query however you want - rename "MRN" to whatever you want, it's just a column name.